# angularTS to PHP file upload "files is empty"

Tags: php, angular, file, input, angular6

I have a trouble - I can't send uploaded file (file seems like empty) from input in frontend to my php backend, and I can't get access to content in "files".

My task: create some form when user can choose *.csv file, send this file on server, parse and save data from *.csv in SQL Table and other things...

**dataload.component.html:**

```
<div>   <input type="file" (change)="doUpload($event)"/> </div>
```

**dataload.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from '../http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dataload',
  templateUrl: './dataload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dataload.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})
export class DataloadComponent {
  files: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

  doUpload(event){
    let target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    this.files = target.files;

    console.log ('Files: ',this.files);

    const apiURL = 'There is my https://testAPI.php';

    this.http.post(apiURL, {'action': 'action','data': this.files})
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("Done. Response JSON: ",data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

**testAPI.php**

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: text/html');
header ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

require_once("includes/connection.php");

$datafile = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($datafile);

$action = $obj->{'action'};
$data = file_get_contents($obj->{'data'});


      $retArr = array(
                      'text' => "Action = ".$action,
                      'mess' => 'Data = '.$data
                    );

echo json_encode(array_values($retArr));
?>
```

**RESULT:**

When I choose file (*.csv) in console I see that:
[console.log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3cXK.jpg)

I tried use papaparse and ngx-papaparse, but I had problem with installation, I tried parse on frontend side for translate to JSON, but I can't get access to content in "this.files", I tried parse on backend side, but on server side same problem...

Help me please, I'm confused :(

Comment: You have to use formData to sending file to server

Comment: I’ve used, but result is same.

Comment: `doUpload(event){
    let target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    this.files = target.files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',this.files)
    
    console.log('Files: ',this.files);
    console.log('formData: ',formData);


    const apiURL = 'There is my https://testAPI.php';

    this.http.post(apiURL, {'action': 'action','formData': formData})
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log("Done. Response JSON: ",data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error: ', error);
        }
      );
  }`

Comment: @PareshGami maybe I should do something else in server side?

Comment: PHP side try print_r($_FILES)